# Returning a boolean from a UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I've had trouble getting a UIAlert return a boolean value, and I could't really find anything online, so I was hoping you guys could help out. Firstly, this is what the basic setup of the [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6pET.png). Basically, when the user clicks the "click" button, an alert pops up, with the choices of "YES" and "NO". Here's the code I have setup for the button so far:

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Choose"
                                                                message:@"Answer the question" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *defaultAction= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:nil];
UIAlertAction *noAction= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"NO" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[alert addAction:noAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I exactly use the completion option to return a bool?

Comment: You can't really find anything?  Really?  How about the following topic?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831468/x-code-obj-c-retrieve-user-inputed-text-from-alert-box-ios8  I can find more.

Comment: You can't return anything from an action handler, but you can set a variable that you check after the controller is dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use completion handler in the UIAlertAction itself. For example,

```
  UIAlertAction *noAction= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"NO" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"NO");
                                  [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                              }];
```